Using TypedResults with Task.FromResult
I have an Asp.Net Core minimal api web app. I want to use the TypedResults in one of my async endpoints. I haven't written the content of the endpoint so I just created a stub with Task.FromResult. However Visual Studio considers it an error:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyRouteHandlerClass
    {
        public Results<Ok, BadRequest> HandleRoute()
        {
            return TypedResults.Ok();  // this is fine
        }

        public Task<Results<Ok, BadRequest>> HandleRouteAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(TypedResults.Ok());  // error
        }

        public async Task<Results<Ok, BadRequest>> HandleRouteReallyAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            return TypedResults.Ok();  // this is also fine
        }
    }
}

The error is: CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults.Ok>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults.Results<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults.Ok, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults.BadRequest>>'
How to correct the Task.FromResult statement?
